# empty dataframe, filtering dataframe with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I have a dataframe that I need to loop through to identify rows that do not match key value pairs.  All keys are distinct, but values may repeat.

When I use code that works outside of the loop, it generates an empty dataframe.  I've confirmed that there are rows that should be included (keys and values exist in the dataframe).

Some sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,10,size=(15, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
dept = {7: [5], 8: [7], 5: [9, 10], 9: [9]}

nd = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in dept.items():
    f = df.loc[df['A']==key, :]
    ff = f.loc[~f['B'].isin(value), :]
    print(type(ff))
    print(ff.shape)
    nd.append(ff)
print(nd)
```

I receive the following output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(4, 4)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(1, 4)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(2, 4)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
(1, 4)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Since the shape's are accurate, I believe this has to do with the <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> type.  How can I extract my dataframes from this type?

I've searched high and low on stack overflow, but haven't found this type of example.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try concat:

```
nd = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in dept.items():
    f = df.loc[df['A']==key, :]
    ff = f.loc[~f['B'].isin(value), :]
    print(type(ff))
    print(ff.shape)

    frames = [nd, ff]
    nd = pd.concat(frames)
print(nd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is using a [`series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) , then filter using [`df.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
(df.assign(E=df['A'].map(dept)).dropna(subset=['E']).explode('E').query("B!=E")
                                               .drop("E",1).drop_duplicates())
```

---

```
    A  B  C  D
2   9  6  7  6
5   8  9  7  5
6   8  5  7  5
8   9  8  9  8
10  7  7  7  5
11  5  5  8  7
12  9  7  8  8
13  9  6  8  8
14  9  6  9  9
```